# Can PHP foreach() handle }else{ and }elseif{?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make my login work, the problem is whenever i press Sign Up i get an error, as i see the line 112 is the }else{, so im wondering, is there a work around for the ELSE part on a foreach? Thanks!

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 112

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['password_login'])){
  $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['user_login']);
  $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['password_login']);
  $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);

  $sql = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password, FROM  users WHERE username = :user_login, password = ":password_login_md5"');
  $sql->bindParam(':user_login', $user_login);
  $sql->bindParam(':password_login_md5', $password_login_md5);
  $sql->execute();
  $userCount = $sql->rowCount();

  foreach($userCount as $row){

    if($row > 0){
      $id = $row['id'];
    }
    $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
  }else{
    echo "That information is incorrect, try again";
  }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this is what i have now:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['password_login'])){
  $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['user_login']);
  $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['password_login']);
  $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);

  $sql = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password, FROM  users WHERE username = :user_login, password = ":password_login_md5"');
  $sql->bindParam(':user_login', $user_login);
  $sql->bindParam(':password_login_md5', $password_login_md5);
  $sql->execute();
  $userCount = $sql->rowCount();
  if($userCount){
    foreach($userCount as $row){
      if($row > 0){
        $id = $row['id'];
      }
    }
  }else{
    echo "information incorrect";
  }
}
```

No errors in there, just whenever i press Login i get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php:101 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php(101): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 101

And i think, im 100% sure that its my query...

Comment: No,only `if` blocks can have an else block, but you can use `if (is_array()) {` before the loop (or `empty()`, whichever is better for you), and that statement can have an `else` block.

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish? 'else' does not really make sense in a foreach since foreach is not a conditional statement.

Comment: `}else{` need to be last of `if`. As well `}` is extra in your case

Comment: I changed in too a script someone told me down here, look at my edit

Comment: Also, `$userCount` isn't an array - it's an integer. This means that you'll get "Invalid argument supplemented in foreach".

Comment: Remove the quotes around the second sql parameter.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' password = '6173354d4e1fd812382752fcb2d0973e'' at line 1' in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php:101 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php(101): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 101
It keeps coming haha

Comment: `SELECT id,username,password, FROM  users WHERE username = :user_login AND password = :password_login_md5`

Comment: So if my password was `#*(((&&^^"""""`, someone could login with my username and an empty password?  That filter weakens password strength.

Comment: Yeah well, i already tried without filter, it keeps coming up with new errors

Comment: Why do you have `password = ":password_login_md5"` in your query? You're using a placeholder, and the quoting will be done for you when you bind the parameters

Answer (score 1):

You should do a check on the `$userCount` variable. There is no `foreach else`.

```
if ($userCount) {
    foreach($userCount as $row){
        ...
    }
 }else{
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Because Luc is calling `exit()` in every execution path of the loop's body (at least in the original snippet), there's no need for the `if` statement. Simply removing the `else` and its brackets in this code would do the same thing.

Comment: Allright i removed the else and everything, it is working but theres a new small problem which i stumbled on earlier,

Comment: I think you should re-phrase the question and there are several other questions out there with what look like answers to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585535/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-ma