# I have a problem with updating a row or a single PHP-PDO data

Tags: php

I can't fully understand the problem.

I am creating a CRUD is the function pupil insert, delete as well. I'm having trouble with the update. It  brings me: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens etc. etc.

I tried entering PDO::PARAM_INT but it always reports the same thing.

```
<?php 
include 'dbconnection.php';
//Ottieni l'ID utente
$userid=intval($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, cognome, idlezione FROM allievi WHERE id=:uid";

//Prepara la query:
$query = $dbconnection->prepare($sql);
//Associa i parametri
$query->bindParam(':uid',$userid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
//Esegui la query:
$query->execute();
//Assegna i dati estratti dal database (nel passaggio precedente) a una variabile.
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//Per l'inizializzazione del numero di serie
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
//Nel caso in cui la query abbia restituito almeno un record, possiamo echo i record all'interno di un ciclo foreach:
foreach($results as $result)
{
$Nome = $result->nome;
$Cognome = $result->cognome;
$Idlezione = $result->idlezione;    
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//Ottieni l'ID utente
$userid=intval($_GET['id']);
//Imposta i valori
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$idlezione = $_POST['idlezione'];
//Query di aggiornamento
$sql="UPDATE alunni SET nome=:nome, cognome=:cognome, idlezione=:idlezione WHERE id=:uid";

//Prepara la query per l'esecuzione
$query = $dbconnection->prepare($sql);
//Associa i parametri
$query->bindParam(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':cognome',$cognome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':idlezione',$idlezione,PDO::PARAM_STR);
//Esegui la query
$query->execute();
//Messaggio di esecuzione
echo "<script>alert('Alunno modificato con successo!');</script>";
//Re-indirizzo 
echo "<script>window.location.href='allievi_tab.php'</script>";
}
    ?> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Modifica i dati dell'alunno</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Nome" required="" value="<?php echo $Nome;?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cognome">Cognome</label>
                                <input type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Cognome" required="" value="<?php echo $Cognome; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="idlezione">Id Lezione</label>
                                <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="idlezione" id="idlezione" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Inserisci il numero della lezione" required="" value="<?php echo $Idlezione;?>">
                            </div>
                               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.centered-form{
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.centered-form .panel{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 20px 20px 20px;
}
    </style>
```

The table is like this:

```
ID P.K. A.I.
NAME VARCHAR(25)
SURNAME VARCHAR(25)
IDLESSON INT(11)
```

Comment: You're not binding the `:uid` parameter in the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585535/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-ma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 variables to bind, you are missing a binding for `:uid`

```php
$query->bindParam(':uid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thank you.

I hadn't really thought about it.